# Why is my PHP code not working?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have made a code --

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/javascript");
require_once('../php/config.php');
$domail_theme = $_GET['theme'];

?>

<?php
  if($domail_theme=='default')
  {
?>

  $('div.theme_content').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      backgroundColor : '#234'
    }, 250, 'linear', function() { });
  });

  $('div.').mouseout(function () {
    $(this).animate({
      backgroundColor : '#ddd'
    }, 400, 'linear', function() { });
  });

<?php
  }
?>
```

And here is the script including tag --

```
<script src="domail_res/scripts/java/settings_form_css.php?theme=default"></script>
```

The thing I want is that when I mouse over on the `div` element with class `theme_content` it's background changes according to the given one in the animate function. It is working for the `input` element but that script is original `javascript` and in this I have included `php` that's why I'm thinking whether the `php` code I used is wrong or my `javascript`. Also when I include this code in `javascript` file it works correctly. And by the I'm including the `script` tag in between the `body` tag, is it wrong? Please help me out with this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you define *"not working"* ? It you call the URL of that script, used in your `<script>` tag, what output do you get ? any error ?

Comment: No I don't get any error on viewing the URL of the script. In fact it shows me the `java` code that I have included in it. Please if you know anything then help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put it inside script. `<script></script>`

And also it's possible that DOM might not have been loaded. so try putting wrappint in `$(document).ready(function() { /*Your code here*/})`

And also put `alert('hello');` to check if that code is being executed or not. It might be  useful in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The most likly explanation is that 'theme" is not set to 'default' in your URL request.

This should be easy to check. Also you can  "View" -> "Page Source" in your browser and look at the html your php program is actually generating. If my guess is right you won't see your mouseover function in the page.

Comment: Sorry, James Anderson, but I have included in it. If you have any suggestions about why I'm not getting the effect on mouse hovering on the specified element, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should write like this:-

```
<?php
 if($domail_theme=='default')
{
?>
<script>

$('div.theme_content').mouseover(function () {
$(this).stop().animate({
  backgroundColor : '#234'
}, 250, 'linear', function() { });
});

$('div.').mouseout(function () {
$(this).animate({
  backgroundColor : '#ddd'
}, 400, 'linear', function() { });
});
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Just need add  tag between on your php if statement.

Hope can help you.

Comment: He's already loading the script with a script src="" directive.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work better if you add type='text/javascript' to your script tag?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="domail_res/scripts/java/settings_form_css.php?theme=default"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the php logic in your main file and include the javascript as plain javascript?

```
<?php
 if($domail_theme=='default')
{
?>
<script type='text/javascript' src="domail_res/scripts/java/settings_form_css.js"></script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Seems like overcomplicating things